# PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a script but keep getting stuck.

I have a variable `$message`. I want to parse it. So that everything contained between * and * could be a different color. For example:

```
This is message * 1
```

Wouldn't be effected. But

```
This is a *message* see how it works *again here*.
```

Would have `message` and `again here` in a different color.

Comment: Ok the script seems to be present on this site lol the italic text here is the text I would wnat to change colors (wrapped in *)

Comment: Yeah, and that looks a bit dodgy as you're using StackOverflow markup. Please add backticks (`) to the phrases.

Comment: I'm just wondering what this has to do with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regexpes:

```
$in = 'This is a *message* see how it works *again here*.';
$out = preg_replace('/\*([^*]+)\*/', '<span class="color">$1</span>', $in);
print $out;
```

little faster than non-greedy matches.

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` to split the string on the asterisks. After that, you can output each element in the array, with the right markup inbetween to change the color.

Something like this:

```
$parts = explode('*', $message);

$italic = false;
for ($part in $parts)
{
  if ($italic) 
    echo '<i>' . $part . '</i>';
  else 
    echo $part;

  $italic = !$italic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of `preg_replace()`:

```
$message = preg_replace("#\*(.*?)\*#", "<span class=\"color-red\">\\1</span>", $message);
```

Comment: Either or would work. I've always been partial to `\\1`. Makes it look less like a PHP variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = preg_replace('/\*([^*]+)\*/', '<em>$1</em>', $message);
```

or

```
$output = preg_replace('/\*(.+?)\*/', '<em>$1</em>', $message);
```

Comment: I'd use `([^*]+)` as the capture pattern, for clarity. The `[^*]` to strictly specify we're looking for anything that isn't an asterisk, and the `+` instead of the `*` to only format anything which contains text inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = 'This is a *message* see how it works *again here*.';
$colorMessage =  preg_replace('/\*([^\*]+|[\w]+)\*/', "<span class='color2'>$0</span>", $message);
```